# Large navigation bar custom height

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, large-title

Is it possible to change large navigation bar height?

```
self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always 
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(expandedNavBar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found this way:

```
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 200
let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [ .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]

let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    if let appearance = navigationBar?.standardAppearance {
        appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = attributes
        navigationBar?.standardAppearance = appearance
        navigationBar?.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }
} else {
    navigationBar?.largeTitleTextAttributes = attributes
}
```

Comment: Please note, works only for iOS 13 and above.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can change navigationBar height because of `Apple HIG`. If you want to change navigationBar height , you can remove navigationBar and you can show your own customview to user like navigationBar

If you want to make the navigationBar a little bigger, you can try this trick by adding an empty string to the prompt property.

```
self.navigationItem.prompt = ""
```

Comment: It adds space on top and move icons but I need extra space on bottom.

Comment: Then you need to do first option . You must remove navigationBar and make your own customView

Comment: You can also add customview directly to the page (top of the Viewcontroller , right under the navigationbar) without removing the navigationbar.But there is no way to do it with navigationBar @ChikabuZ

Comment: I'm looking for better solution.